# Rotate Selected Image with jQueryRotate In chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I need to rotate images by clicking in an context menu option...
something like this.[image: Image of an extension with a context menu with four options]

Im trying to develop the extension using JQueryRotate and JQueryEasing.
Here´s an example of the code that i wanna use
http://jsfiddle.net/8xwqdk71/ (i dont embed the code because it shows me an error)

My problem is that i dont know how to apply this code into my extension, i read the only few examples that are on the web and they only focus on using JqueryRotate in a webpage and not in a extension. I will appreciate any information or examples that any of you can give me

this are my files right now:

**manifest.json**

```js
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "image rotator",
  "author": "me",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "i rotate images",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon-large.png",
    "default_popup": ""
  },

  "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "contextMenus"
  ],
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon-bitty.png",
    "48": "icon-small.png",
    "128": "icon-large.png"
  }
}
```

**background.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.easing.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jQueryRotate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="menus.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**menus.js**

```js
///// Parent contextMenu /////

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Image rotator",
    contexts: ["all"],
    id: "parent",
});

///// First submenu Context Menu /////

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Rotar 90",
    contexts:["all"],
    parentId: "parent",
    id: "child1",
    onclick: child1Search,
});
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Rotar -90",
    contexts:["all"],
    parentId: "parent",
    id: "child2",
    onclick: child2Search,
});
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Rotar 180",
    contexts:["all"],
    parentId: "parent",
    id: "child3",
    onclick: child3Search,
});
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Rotar -180",
    contexts:["all"],
    parentId: "parent",
    id: "child4",
    onclick: child4Search,
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found some old extension files from the extension IMG Rotate, and update them because they use precarious methods. but they dont use jQueryRotate.

**Manifest.json**

```js
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Rotar ",
    "version": "1.0",
    "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },
    "permissions" : [
        "contextMenus",
        "tabs",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
    ],
    "content_scripts" : [
        {
            "matches": [
                "http://*/*",
                "https://*/*"
            ],
            "js": ["jquery-1.5.2.min","contentscript.js"]
        }
    ],
    "icons" : {
        "16" : "icon-bitty.png",
        "48" : "icon-small.png",
        "128" : "icon-large.png"
    }
}
```

**background.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.2.min"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="contentscript.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="background.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**background.js**

```js
        /**
         * Returns a handler which will open a new window when activated.
         */
        function rotateClockWise() {
            return function (info, tab1) {
                chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
                    chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {angle: 90, rotation: 'rotate'}, function(response) {

                    });
                });
            };
        }

        function rotateCounterClockWise() {
            return function (info, tab1) {
                chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
                    chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {angle: -90, rotation: 'rotate'}, function(response) {

                    });
                });
            };
        }

        function upright() {
            return function (info, tab1) {
                chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
                    chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {angle: 0, rotation: 'flip'}, function(response) {

                    });
                });
            };
        }

        function upsideDown() {
            return function (info, tab1) {
                chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
                    chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {angle: 180, rotation: 'flip'}, function(response) {

                    });
                });
            };
        }


        /**
         * Create a context menu which will only show up for images.
         */
        chrome.contextMenus.create({
                    "title" : "Rotar 90",
                    "type" : "normal",
                    "contexts" : ["all"],
                    "onclick" : rotateClockWise()
                });

        chrome.contextMenus.create({
                    "title" : "Rotar -90",
                    "type" : "normal",
                    "contexts" : ["all"],
                    "onclick" : rotateCounterClockWise()
                });

        chrome.contextMenus.create({
                    "title" : "Rotar 180",
                    "type" : "normal",
                    "contexts" : ["all"],
                    "onclick" : upsideDown()
                });

        chrome.contextMenus.create({
                    "title" : "Rotar -180",
                    "type" : "normal",
                    "contexts" : ["all"],
                    "onclick" : upright()
                });
```

**contentscript.js**

```js
var selectedImage = null;
$("*", document.body).mousedown(function (event) {
    switch (event.which) {
        case 3:
            selectedImage = $(this).get(0);
            event.stopPropagation();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
});

chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(onRequest);

function onRequest(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    var degree;
    if (request.rotation == 'flip') {
        degree = request.angle;
    } else {
        degree = getCurrentRotation(request.angle);
    }
    selectedImage.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)';
    sendResponse({}); // clean up.
}

function getCurrentRotation(angle) {
    var currentDegree = selectedImage.style['-webkit-transform'];
    if (currentDegree && currentDegree != "") {
        var start = currentDegree.indexOf('(');
        var end = currentDegree.indexOf('deg)');
        angle = parseInt(currentDegree.substring(start + 1, end)) + angle;
    }
    return angle;
}
```

And you also need jquery to make this work
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to use *jQueryRotate*, but here is the pure js way with the same effect.

So, you need a background script to create context menus and a content-script to handle rotation.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Rotar",
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "content_scripts": [{
    "js": ["content-script.js"],
    "matches": [
      "http://*/*",
      "https://*/*"
    ],
    "run_at": "document_end",
    "all_frames": true
  }],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "contextMenus"
  ]
}
```

**background.js**

Background script sends a message with rotation degree when context item was clicked.
Please note, that I've changed `contexts:["all"]` to `contexts:["image"]`.

```js
///// Parent contextMenu /////

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Image rotator",
    contexts: ["image"],
    id: "parent",
});

///// First submenu Context Menu /////

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Rotar 90",
    contexts:["image"],
    parentId: "parent",
    id: "child1",
    onclick: rotate.bind(null, '90'),
});
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Rotar -90",
    contexts:["image"],
    parentId: "parent",
    id: "child2",
    onclick: rotate.bind(null, '-90'),
});
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Rotar 180",
    contexts:["image"],
    parentId: "parent",
    id: "child3",
    onclick: rotate.bind(null, '180'),
});
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "Rotar -180",
    contexts:["image"],
    parentId: "parent",
    id: "child4",
    onclick: rotate.bind(null, '-180'),
});

/**
 * Sends message to content-script 
 */
function rotate(deg, event, tab) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {
        deg: deg
    }, {
        frameId: event.frameId
    });
}
```

**content-script.js**

Content-script tracks all images that have been clicked by right mouse button and applies CSS rotation when receiving the message.

```js
let lastClickedImage = null;

document.body.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    if(e.target.matches('img') && e.button === 2) { // right click to an image
        lastClickedImage = e.target;
    }
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(request => {
    if(lastClickedImage) {
        lastClickedImage.style.transition = 'transform 0.5s ease';
        lastClickedImage.style.transform = 'rotate(' + request.deg + 'deg)';
    }
});
```

Comment: I check the code you give me and it only shows the context menus, but doesnt do anything when i tested it on the browser

Comment: @holyTrap Did you reload tabs after the extension was added? I tried it on Google main page.

Comment: yes, i try exactly the code you give me like 6 times... i restart the browser and modify some parameters but still does the same thing

Comment: @holyTrap, any errors in the background or content-script consoles?

Comment: well, i tested it on most of the website i use, and i have another 2 extension that rotate images, 1 is IMG rotate, and the other is Flip This, both work perfectly but when i use the one you give me it doesnt work

Comment: try to use http://www.ddginc-usa.com/text-compare-tool.htm to compare the code you give me with the code you have...

Comment: @holyTrap I just copied the code above into new files and check again - it works for me. Try to debug content-script: does it receive the message? does it have latest clicked image?